# Send build status from Travis to Sauce Labs

Tags: selenium, gruntjs, travis-ci, karma-runner, saucelabs

I have my testing up and running with Travis/SauceLabs. Now I would like to add a SauceLabs test badge to my repo.

I added the badge markdown to my Readme file but how can I send the build pass/fail to SauceLabs? I found [**this instructions**](https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#passed) for Selenium,

> **Key:**   passed
>   **Value type:** bool
>   **Example**:    "passed": true

but how/where do I add info in my files for my Grunt-Karma/Travis/SauceLabs testing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Karma-Sauce-Launcher was using the wrong `id`, and this was fixed on Github by [this PR](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma-sauce-launcher/pull/29) and released in NPM as version `0.2.5`

Aditionally the saucelabs reporter has to be added to the gruntfile options, besides the existing ones or the default `progress`.

So the bugfix I added to my package.json:

```
"karma-sauce-launcher": "~0.2.5"
```

and added this:

```
reporters: ['progress', 'saucelabs'],
```

in the Karma options.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the [REST API](https://saucelabs.com/docs/additional-config#alternative-annotation-methods). What you would do is add code in a function that is executed at the very end of your test suite and knows the result of your test run. This code would have to perform a query equivalent to this `curl` command:

```
$ curl -H "Content-Type:text/json" -s -X PUT -d '{"passed": <status>}' http://<username>:<key>@saucelabs.com/rest/v1/<username>/jobs/<job-id>
```

(The identifiers in angular brackets have to be replaced with appropriate values.)

I've done it with Python but I don't have JavaScript code to share. And by the way, you have to do this for Selenium too because as the documentation states, when Selenium sends the job data to Sauce Labs, it cannot know yet what the test result is going to be.

Comment: Louis, thanks for checking this out! where would i use it with javscript? in the Gruntfile? can I just open that url passint the object in a query string?

Comment: What test runner do you use? The mention of Grunt and Travis-ci in your question leaves the door wide open to all kinds of possibilities. (You could be using Mocha, or Jasmine, or something else.) *The runner* is what will dictate where you put the check. And on the topic of Travis-ci... are you running your own instance or are you relying on travis-ci.org? If the latter then be aware that if you must perform the Sauce Labs status update from *there* you'd be putting sensitive information (`<username>:<key>`) onto a public server.

Comment: Regarding the repo: yikes!!! I know Mocha but don't know Jasmine. Jasmine looks a lot like Mocha but... it does not support `after` (aka `afterAll`). In Mocha the location for the status update would be in the `after` callback for the topmost `describe`. At that point, you know whether the suite has been successful or not. I don't know of an equivalent for Jasmine. Someone has produced a [patch](https://github.com/nonplus/jasmine-beforeAll) to add it to Jasmine.

Comment: I'd just rather not have third parties using my account.

Comment: sure... nice link to the Jasmin patch btw!

Comment: Louis, where did you run the `curl` from? I am trying to run it from my .yml file in the `after_success:` script but keep getting errors...

Comment: That `curl` command was for illustration purposes. I've adapted it from the Sauce Labs documentation. As I've mentioned, what I actually did was write a routine in Python that does something equivalent in an `after_all` handler for a suite run by [behave](https://pythonhosted.org/behave/index.html). What error are you getting?

Comment: When Travis runs the command it looks like it wrapps the line with `{}` so it looks like `$ {:"curl -H \"Content-Type:text/json\" -s -X PUT -d '{\"passed\""=>"true}' http://$SAUCE_USERNAME:$SAUCE_ACCESS_KEY@saucelabs.com/rest/v1/$SAUCE_USERNAME/jobs/$TRAVIS_JOB_ID"}` (the env variables resolve good, I can see that on the log. I tried also running that CURL from my Mac command line and I get back a JSON object with a error message.

Comment: I'd expect the data (after `-d`) to be `{"passed": true}` (or `{"passed": false}`. It has to be valid JSON. And I can't see how `$TRAVIS_JOB_ID` can be right. Surely Travis assigns an Travis job ID which is different from the ID Sauce Labs assigns to its jobs, no? You need the Sauce Labs ID.

Comment: Louis, again, thanks for feedback. I've been trying more since I last commented here. So you think `$TRAVIS_JOB_ID` is the wrong thing, now I wonder where I can find the SL job ID into Travis, and back to SL.

Comment: It can be extracted from the webdriver instance your test suite starts. In Python, if `driver` is an instance, then `driver.session_id` (Yes, *session* not *job*. Go figure...) Selenium names are similar from language to language to I'd expect something close in JavaScript. The easiest thing would probably be to shove it into a temporary file and have your `curl` command read it. In a shell command you can read a file with `$(<path/to/file)`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using Grunt already, you should use https://github.com/axemclion/grunt-saucelabs as it is the official plug-in that is worked on by devs from SauceLabs.

Comment: Hmmm... very interesting! and exactly where do I send the pass/failed info? I will check it out in the meantime...

Comment: It handles all the sauce tunnel and reporting for you

Comment: I've checked it better now. It does not work and report "out of the box". It needs `Jasmine JS Reporter` which I didn't manage to get working. Have you tried/got it working?

Comment: I see you are involved in the repo also. Nice.

Comment: Yes, I did. Thank you. In the end of that page is [the badge link](https://saucelabs.com/docs/status-images), that's were I still am since I started this question.

Comment: What is the issue with the instructions in the docs? The badge will represent the latest build automatically. Ex https://saucelabs.com/browser-matrix/wet-boew-bot.svg or https://saucelabs.com/buildstatus/wet-boew-bot

Comment: The thing is that just adding the badge to the Readme file is not enough. There needs to be a callback or report function to SL to say if the test exited with 0 or not. In your case you are using __[Jasmine Reporter](https://github.com/axemclion/grunt-saucelabs/blob/master/test/jasmine/SpecRunner.html#L11)__ but that is not my first option since my specs don't have a HTML page like yours.